# show a file picker in android like Telegeram or WhatsApp

Tags: android

I'm trying to browse all files and document in android like below
[image]

then select a document  like this:
[image]

then select other apps document like this:
[image]

I tried this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"), 1);
```

and the result is this:
[image]

I do not know what I should do

Comment: All you need is a custom file picker. You can either create one by yourself or better still, look one up on Github.

Comment: @DevMike01 Thank you very much indeed, I have done it
The main problem is the fact that I could not see all the files and documents in my phone
I just have access to the downloads folder and recent, but I need to have access to other folders like Telegram, Whatsapp ...

Comment: @KateBR did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's late but for other that looking for this, you can use https://github.com/smartdevelopers-ir/SmartFilePicker.
This is a file picker library like Telegram's file picker